# Calling HttpGet Method Using Ajax on IpagedListPager Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I want to call HttpGet method on every page using ajax using IpagedList in MVC

Controller [HttpGet]

```
public ActionResult TestStarted(int TestId,DateTime End_Time,int page=1)
        {
            ViewBag.ct = 0;
            ViewBag.TestId = TestId;
            var Questions = GetNoOfQuestions().ToList();

            ViewBag.Questions = Questions;
            EAssessmentNew.BAL.StudentBal studBal = new EAssessmentNew.BAL.StudentBal();
            EAssessmentNew.Dal.Student_Answer_Master _studAnsdal = new EAssessmentNew.Dal.Student_Answer_Master();
            String TestName = studBal.FetchTestName(TestId);
            ViewBag.TestName = TestName;


            ViewBag.EndTime = End_Time;

            List<Question> model = new List<Question>();

            model = new Test_Planning().Fetch_Question_By_Test(TestId);

            ViewBag.total = model.Count();


            if (Request.QueryString["cnt"] != null)
            {
                int count = Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["cnt"].ToString());


                List<int> ChkOptions = studBal.GetCheckedAnswers((int)TestId, model[count].QuestionId, (int)(studBal.getStudentId(Session["sname"].ToString())));
                ViewBag.ChkOptions = ChkOptions;
                int cnt = 0;



                    if (ChkOptions.Count() != 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < model[count].Options.Count(); i++)
                        {


                            if (model[count].Options[i].OptionId == ChkOptions.ElementAt(cnt))
                            {
                                model[count].Options[i].IsChecked = true;
                                cnt++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                model[count].Options[i].IsChecked = false;
                            }

                            if (cnt >= ChkOptions.Count() - 1)
                            {
                                cnt = ChkOptions.Count() - 1;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                return View(model.OrderByDescending(v => v.Question_Id).ToPagedList(page, 1));
            }
            else
            {
                return View(model.OrderByDescending(v => v.Question_Id).ToPagedList(page, 1));
            }
        }
```

My View

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var TestId ='@ViewBag.TestId'
 function loadQuestions() {
            alert("ok")
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Student","TestStarted")',
                data: { TestId:TestId },
                contentType:"application/json",
                success:function(responce){                   

                }
            });
        }

    </script>


    <div class="pagedList">
            @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action( "",new { onclick="loadQuestions()"}), PagedListRenderOptions.TwitterBootstrapPager)
        </div>
```

I have done paging using IpagedList i want to call HttpGet Method Of controller on each and every page but i want this to perform without page refresh i have written ajax for it now i just want to know how can i call that ajax method using @Html.PagedListPager and on onClick event

Comment: You can use the `PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions () {HttpMethod = "GET" UpdateTargetId = ....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Correct your url in ajax request as :

Instead of this

```
url: '@Url.Action("Student","TestStarted")'
```

It should be this

```
url: '@Url.Action("TestStarted","Student")'
```

and `@Html.PagedListPager` produces `'anchor'` tag in html so you can put a click event on document as shown :-

```
 $(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: "html",
        data :{  TestId : $("#TestId").val(), End_Time :$("#End_Time").val(), page :$("#page").val() }
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $('#results').html('');
            $('#results').html(result);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

In above code click event binds with every `'anchor'` tag so if you need for specific `'anchor'` tags then you can specify class as `$(.pager).on('click', 'a', function() {})` and here `'#results'` is the target div id whose html is coming from controller action in your case this id may be different.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59935/discussion-on-answer-by-exception-calling-httpget-method-using-ajax-on-ipagedlis).